# Sending notifications at a set time interval with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, timer, push-notification

Using Flask for a backend API.

Endpoint sends a notification to the first user in a list of users, if the user does not respond within an hour, that user is removed from the list and a notification is sent to the next user.

What is the best way to implement this timed sending functionality? From what I can gather Threading will result in to many threads, and Celery may be overkill?

Any suggestions and help is very appreciated!

Comment: Depending on your hosting service or current OS, you can set a timed script to run every hour that performs the operation your detailed. The API chronicles all responses from users during that time and saves the response to a file or database, which can then be read by the timed script.